# Random gray horizontal lines in Google Sheets - using Chrome and Opera

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome, opera

[image]Since about 1 month ago, I've been getting random gray lines (only horizontal) in my Google Sheets. I use Chrome exclusively. If I scroll down to the bottom of the page, the lines disappear. But later they come back.

I'm getting the gray lines in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox. I have made sure I have the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Can you supply a screen shot? Does it happen in other browsers? Have you made sure that Chrome is updated to the latest version?

Comment: Is the same in Opera, but not in firefox?! and yes, I have the most up to date chrome version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information. Comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: Please add more details like, the version of Chrome/Opera that you are using, the name and version of you operative system, the zoom setting of your browser, if you already tried using your browsers on private navigation mode with all the extensions turned off. Also include information about the Google Sheets add-ons that you have installed and if you have the show gridlines setting turned on/off.

Comment: @ Ruben. it looks like it was the zoom settings. I was on 110%, now at 100% and the gray lines disappeared! thanks for the comments. It looks like 110% is the only setting where those lines appear. No gray lines appear on 125%, or 150%.

Comment: @jason: Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jason is right: been having the same issue and going back to a 100% zoom "fixed it". It seems Google Sheet does not handle a 110% zoom very well.